# Testing observer based on the reactiveVal in shiny::testServer

Tags: r, unit-testing, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have following problem when testing `shiny` module where observer depends on the change of the reactive value.

```r
srv_module <- function(id, n) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- eventReactive(n(), ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
      runif(n())
    })
    
    observeEvent(data(), ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
      message("hi")
    })
  })
}
```

Following test should return value of the `data` which works but also should print the message from the observer which does not happen.

```
testServer(
  srv_module, 
  args = list(id = "test", n = reactiveVal(1)),
  expr = {
    print(data())
  } 
)
```

Does anyone knows the way to trigger the `observeEvent`?

Thanks!